# sqlite3: SQL error: database or disk is full

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have created a fresh sqlite3 database and inserted around 50 million rows into table infotable. Now when I am trying to run the below query it gives me 'database or disk is full'.

Query:

```
select ID, count(ID) as cnt from infotable group by ID order by cnt desc limit 20;
```

The count for ID can vary from 1-1000

Database size is 7.5G while available space at local area is 116G.

I am not sure the reason behind this as I can not see any space issue on the disk.  I am using SQLite version 3.3.6 on Linux machine. Is it related to some confrontational change in the database.

Thanks

Comment: How big is the database file? What is the output of `df`?

Comment: @CL updated the size details in my question. One more thing to add here is, this is working with a similar database/table with less rows and 4G size.

Comment: What is the output if `df`?